# rasterize.js to convert svg to png

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, png, rasterize

I have been using phantomjs to create headless screenshots. 
This is how I usually do it:

phantomjs phantom-crowbar.js my-path/index.html mysvg bubble.svg

phantomjs rasterize.js bubble.svg bubble.png

When this is run locally, it works perfectly and creates the required png.
However, when it is run on a remote host, the svg is created properly, but when I run the rasterize.js step, the png is not created in its entirety. The text from the svg does not show up in the png. I have tried increasing the timeout period in rasterize.js but that won't work.

Comment: do your server has the appropiate fonts? or altternate

Comment: Should that really matter considering the svg is created correctly with the font. It's the part where the svg is converted to png that does not work.

Comment: You will find rasterize.js here: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js